# Make UITableView rows selectable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I am currently writing a game for the iOS platform.
In the start-a-new-game view, I have a `UITableView` embedded in a `UINavigationController`.
Each cell in the  table view has the name of a person in the player's friend list, and I wish to make it possible for the player to select a set of friends to invite to play a new game.

My question is: How do I make rows in a `UITableView` selectable and then add the selected rows to an `NSArray`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UITableViewController`'s `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is the delegate method that makes the rows *selectable*.

As per your requirement right now, this is all you need.

You can wire logic in this delegate to perform an action on the row that a user clicks on.

Simple Example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"%@",cell.textLabel.text];

    //declare "NSMutableArray *myMutableArray;" in the .h of this class
    //now you can add objects to it with the following:
    [myMutableArray addObject:cell.textLabel.text];
    //note: this is not perfect. it will add the cell's text everytime you
    //click any row, which means... duplicate entries.
}
```

The first line takes the info regarding the particular cell.
The second line is a simple demonstration that prints the text you have in that cell.
You can do more than this depending on your logic.

ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I will accept the answer as soon as I am able (4 mins)

Comment: @HenrikHillestadLøvold: no probs. i added a simple code example. take a look and improvise.